# load Json file in Javascript not same result on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem and i don't know how solve it.
I would load a json file in Javascript. In firefox it's ok but in chrome, i don't know why but it doesn't work. I have this exception : 
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://france.intra.corp .../pieChart.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
The json file exist and when i search this i find the good file.
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVmfR.png), 
[javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iLnD.png)

Thank you.

Comment: because chrome and firefox handle `file:///` differently - chrome by default does not let you XHR on `file:///`

Comment: Thank you but what could i change in my code? I 'm beginners in this language...

Comment: nothing in your code ... use a web server

Comment: note, there is a command line option in chrome to change this behaviour

Comment: the command line option is `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: I forgot to say : in firefox, the $.ajax() is done because we see the alert(JSON.stringify(json)). But in chrome, it's fail because we see the alert("error")

Comment: Really? so it doesn't work in chrome but does work in firefox? Like you said in the question that has no code? (26 lines total of code, and you're too lazy to put it in the question!?)

Answer (score 0):

in chrome you should use web server url to access your script due to CORS policy.
run your script in a web server start with http://...